# Ember-CLI copy resources from URL to public-folder (triggered by Ember)

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sails.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

My backend-server (Sails) generates a sitemap dynamically which is made available via `http://127.0.0.1/sitemap.xml`. I would like to copy this (and a few RSS-feeds with the same procedure) into the public-folder everytime I trigger it somehow from my Ember-app.

How can I achieve this?

I've seen the https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-static-compiler but I don't know whether that can copy from URLs and also I don't know how to trigger it from my App.